# How to programmatically add constraints to Neo4J Cypher queries

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am writing a sever plugin for Neo4J. The plugin receives a cypher query, and executes it. Currently, my implementation uses a `CypherExecutor`.

I now need to further constrain the results. (For example, imagine that the results need to be filtered by ACLs.)

One approach is to filter the results after executing the query. I'd rather not do this, for performance reasons as well as other limitations (for example, any aggregate results would be wrong.)

I considered adding the constraints to the query itself. I've looked at the `command.AbstractQuery` subclasses produced using the `CypherParser`. That object model is immutable.

I am wondering whether I will need to resort to cloning Neo4J's ExecutionEngine and CypherCompiler, just to extend the ExecutionPlanBuilder... I would like to avoid this option if at all possible.

Any recommendations about how this can be done?

In my case, I am simply trying to simulate multiple isolated graphs. I am OK with how this might be modeled -- whether I add a 'tenantId' to each node, or maintain a tenant node and add `(:Tenant)<-[:scopedTo]-(n)` relationships to every node.

Comment: The best way to do this depends highly on what your "further constraints" are.   Can you provide examples of what the ACLs might be?  Is the relevant data behind the ACLs in neo, or elsewhere?  Where?  What other constraints besides ACLs do you want built in?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; I have added details of what I'm trying to do right now. But the question was of interest to me abstractly. If doing some augmenting of Cypher turns out to be easy, that would affect how I architect future features and APIs...

Comment: So fundamentally, neo4j is for managing data.  So if there's some data you need to inform your decision on what to return...it should be in neo4j!  Then your problem becomes simple: you just change your cypher queries to filter on that extra data that you put in neo4j.   The way you design this scenario assumes you want to filter results based on things not in the database; I'm no expert in all the options for doing that, but it just leaves me scratching my head - why not put it in the DB, then query the DB?  That's what it's for.

Comment: I most certainly want to store the data about project scoping or whatever other usecase in the graph. What I *don't* want to do is to force anyone updating or querying the graph to understand all the different concerns being addressed by the graph. In my above example, I don't want every piece of logic wanting to perform a query to think about multi-tenancy now, ACLs later, etc. Put another way, I want different concerns to be encoded by different bits of logic, and allow Cypher (DOM, ideally) to be the abstraction upon which the different concerns get applied.

Comment: I don't think cypher is currently intended to be extended by the user. That ability will be added as user defined functions along the road. Perhaps you'd rather want to look at a client-side dsl, like CypherDSL? https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/cypher-dsl